# Grouping TransactSql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am new to Transact SQL so take it easy on me ^^

I have the following table named

FuntionSet :

```
storeId   EmployeeId   ContractNum
   1        325003         3326
   2        33625          3369
   1        05             258
   2        56             6235
  ...
```

How can I make the grouping to get the employees per store like the following

```
StoreID  Employee1  Employee2 ...
   1       325003      05
   2       33625       56
  ...
```

Knowing that the number of employees is dynamic, how can I achieve this?

Any help will be welcome ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
select StoreId, [1] as Employee1, [2] as Employee2, ..., [10] as Employee10
from
    (
    select StoreId, EmployeeId,
    row_number(*) (partition by StoreId order by EmployeeId) as rownum
    from T
    ) as SRC
    pivot
    (min(EmployeeId)
        for rownum in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10])
    ) as CT
```

Only handles ten employees per store as written. Substitute your table's name for `T`.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you just want to pivot.

```
select StoreID , EmployeeID as [1]
      from
(
  select StoreID, EmployeeID
  from tableName
)     x
pivot
(
   max(EmployeeID)
   for StoreID in(EmployeeID)p
```

You'll have to play with the select statement to grab exactly what you want

Here is a dynamic SQL way to do this as well.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

 select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.StoreID) 
        FROM temp c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

 set @query = 'SELECT EmployeeID, ' + @cols + ' from 
        (
            select StoreID, EmployeeID
            from temp
       ) x
        pivot 
        (
             max(EmployeeID)
            for StoreIDin (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '


execute(@query)
```